# ASP.NET MVC redirect from asynchronous call

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I send asynchronous call using jQuery form plugin and in the case of success want to redirect user to some "success-page". Now my ASP.NET MVC action just returns some special "success-JSON" and the user is redirected using Javascript.

Is there any way to implement automatic redirect (without Javascript call)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are performing an AJAX call, then the only way to redirect the user is to change the `window.location.href` in the complete callback based on the success JSON code.